# How can you reuse code for similar functions on AWS Lambda?

Tags: design, dry, aws

I have 3 Lambda functions that do very similar things: scrape data from different sections of a website.

Each function returns a collection of objects that have similar properties. The method of fetching of the pages is all the same throughout all 3 functions, only difference is the HTML elements that are being scraped. So total, there are around 150 lines of code that are different because of the different tags needing to be parsed.

How prevent myself from copy pasting code, since each Lambda function is environmentally independent from the others? I also want to keep the zipfile below 15mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be have a generic function that gets the list of tags to be parsed as environment variables. Look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html for more info.

You can pass env variable like

```
aws lambda  create-function \
--region us-east-1 \
--function-name ReturnBucketName \
--zip-file fileb://file-path/Test_Environment_Variables.zip \
--role role-arn \
--environment Variables={S3_BUCKET=Test} \
--handler index.handler \
--runtime nodejs6.10 \
--version  version \
--profile default
```

and access it like

```
process.env.S3_BUCKET
```